# JavaScript - How to store and use return value of the function in a variable

Tags: javascript

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = today;
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() +1);

function formatDateToString(date) { 
  var dd = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') 
      + date.getDate(); 

  return dd;
}
```

how can I store and use the return value in a variable?

Comment: Yes it is ... future is "05", and today is the 4th ... have you even run your code as posted to test? Perhaps the real code is different to what you've posted ... Note .. changing the date of `tomorrow` will change `today` and vice-versa as they are the same object

Comment: you can easily do `var ddResult = formatDateToString();` the return value dd will now be in ddResult.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is returning a value you can assign the returned value to the variable like this:

```
var returned = formatDateToString(date);
```